# Counter not resetting shapes numbering after each slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

In the below macro, I cannot have the shapes `IconDish` and `ChevronNavigator` to reset to 1 for each slide, so that later I can select them for further editing of their properties.
I tried also to place the counter right after the shape is created, but it looks like it does not really matter where it is and the counter does not stop. I also tried to stop it at `iColumn`'s value, but nothing.

```
Option Explicit

Sub NavigatorX()

Dim oSlide As Slide

Dim oShapeNavigator As Shape
Dim IconDishNavigator As Shape
Dim ChevronNavigator As Shape

Dim nCounter As Long

Dim CellLeft As Single
Dim CellTop As Single
Dim CellWidth As Single
Dim CellHeight As Single
Dim CellWidth_2 As Single

Dim iRow As Integer
Dim iColumn As Integer

Dim Shp_Cntr As Single 'Center of Selected Shapes
Dim Shp_Mid As Single 

Dim NavWidth As Single
Dim EvenCell_W As Single

Dim DishCounter As Long
Dim ChevronCounter As Long

ChevronCounter = 0
DishCounter = 0

For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides

    If oSlide.CustomLayout.Name = "Section Header" Then
        nCounter = nCounter + 1

ElseIf nCounter > 0 Then

    Set oShapeNavigator = oSlide.Shapes.AddTable(1, 10, Left:=10, Top:=10, Width:=500, Height:=2)
                        oShapeNavigator.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 128, 128)
                        oShapeNavigator.Name = "Navigator " & nCounter
                                
                              
            With oShapeNavigator.Table      '@@ TABLE @@
    
                For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                For iColumn = 1 To .Columns.Count Step 2
                
                        EvenCell_W = (oShapeNavigator.Width / .Columns.Count / 2) * IIf(iColumn Mod 2 = 0, 5 / 7, 2 / 7)
                                
                        With .Columns(iColumn)
                        
                               .Width = EvenCell_W
                            
                               CellLeft = oShapeNavigator.Table.Cell(iRow, iColumn).Shape.Left
                               CellTop = oShapeNavigator.Table.Cell(iRow, iColumn).Shape.Top
                               CellWidth = oShapeNavigator.Table.Cell(iRow, iColumn).Shape.Width
                               CellHeight = oShapeNavigator.Table.Cell(iRow, iColumn).Shape.Height
                               Debug.Print CellWidth
                               Debug.Print CellHeight
            
                               Shp_Cntr = CellLeft + CellWidth / 2
                               Shp_Mid = CellTop + CellHeight / 2
                               
                                DishCounter = DishCounter + 1  
                                   ' <---- i put it here before, but it was still not counting right
                     
                            Set IconDishNavigator = oSlide.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeOval, Left:=Shp_Cntr - CellHeight / 2, Top:=Shp_Mid - CellHeight / 2, Width:=CellHeight, Height:=CellHeight)
                     
                                   IconDishNavigator.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(100, 250, 140)
                                   IconDishNavigator.Line.Weight = 0.75
                                   IconDishNavigator.Line.Visible = msoFalse
                                   IconDishNavigator.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                                   IconDishNavigator.Name = "IconDish" & DishCounter
                                   
                        End With
                 Next iColumn
                 Next iRow
           End With
'

            With oShapeNavigator.Table      '@@ TABLE @@
                For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                For iColumn = 2 To .Columns.Count Step 2
            
                                
                        With .Columns(iColumn)
                        
'                                   .Width = EvenCell_W
                                
                                   CellLeft = oShapeNavigator.Table.Cell(iRow, iColumn).Shape.Left
                                   CellTop = oShapeNavigator.Table.Cell(iRow, iColumn).Shape.Top
                                   CellWidth = oShapeNavigator.Table.Cell(iRow, iColumn).Shape.Width
                                   CellHeight = oShapeNavigator.Table.Cell(iRow, iColumn).Shape.Height
                                   Debug.Print CellWidth
                                   Debug.Print CellHeight
                
                                   Shp_Cntr = CellLeft + CellWidth / 2
                                   Shp_Mid = CellTop + CellHeight / 2
                                   ChevronCounter = ChevronCounter + 1
                                                        ' <---- i put it here before, but it was still not counting right
                                   
                     
                            Set ChevronNavigator = oSlide.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeChevron, Left:=Shp_Cntr - CellHeight / 2, Top:=Shp_Mid - CellHeight / 2, Width:=CellWidth, Height:=CellHeight)
                                   ChevronNavigator.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(100, 100, 100)
                                   ChevronNavigator.Line.Weight = 0.75
                                   ChevronNavigator.Line.Visible = msoFalse
                                   ChevronNavigator.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                                   ChevronNavigator.Name = "Chevron" & ChevronCounter
                                   

                        End With
            
                Next iColumn
                Next iRow
            
            
            End With

End If
Next oSlide

         DishCounter = 0
         ChevronCounter = 0



End Sub
```

Comment: Probably because you only reset the counters after you have looped through the all the slides. `DishCounter = 0` and `ChevronCounter = 0` should be before `Next oSlide`

Comment: @Timothy great, it was exactly there, thank you.